# Get Java Yelp API keys

Tags: java, api, yelp

how can I get the keys (consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret) to make a request using java yelp api? Is it possible only creating an APP?

Comment: Yes, you need to create an App to get the access keys you want for the API, unless maybe the specific API will allow user-based authentication that gives you tokens

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Looks like Yelp prefers that you have at least a plan to make an application in order to get key.

According to the Yelp documentation help, Yelp is expecting that you have at least a planned application to receive your keys. This is the text that comes from their [authentication page](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/authentication):

> Create an app on Yelp's Developers site
>   In order to set up your access to Yelp Fusion API, you need to create an app with Yelp. This app represents the application you'll build using our API and includes the credentials you'll need to gain access. Here are the steps for creating an app:
>
> Go to Create App In the create new app form, enter information about
>   your app, then agree to Yelp API Terms of Use and Display
>   Requirements. Then click the Submit button. You will now have an API
>   Key.

This is also reinforced with Yelp's [API Terms of use](https://www.yelp.com/developers/api_terms). The registration process is going to have optional fields for a website address, and required fields for a description and name for the application that will eventually be calling the Yelp API.

This doesn't mean that the application has to be complete, though. You can try to specify that there isn't an established name, and that the application isn't complete. When you're approved, you can use Postman our your java program to make calls.

The terms of service doesn't specify exactly how long you have to complete an application before they would terminate your credentials. I have experience just requesting credentials with the NOAA api and others for education and research purposes, and never had my credentials pulled because I don't have a complete application.

Once you have this API key, it looks like that all you need is this API key as your authorization in any rest call to the service:

> starting March 1, 2018 the API no longer uses OAuth 2.0 for requests and moved over to only API Keys.
>
> With just API Keys the process to authenticate is:
>
> Get your API Key from the Manage App page. Put the API Key in the
>   request header as "Authorization: Bearer YOUR API KEY".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created an incomplete application but I got only "Client ID" and "API key".

At this point how I have to validate the variables: consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret in Java Code?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add this information in. However, looks like they recently moved away from OAuth, which needed extra validation variables. Now all you will need is your API Key. When you make a rest call, make sure you include in the request header: "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR API KEY>".